# Powershell multithread and oracle procedure

Tags: multithreading, oracle, powershell, stored-procedures

I have list of files which increase by 5 within the 1 minutes never end. I am inserting this data to Database using oracle procedure. (method external table)

Then i am calling this procedure from Powershell as below.

```
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
    #executing the calculate procedure      
    executeStoredProcedure -value sp_load_table_crm -filename $file.Name -conn 
}
```

This works okay. But it takes long time and wanted to speed up. 
which is the better to use multithreading or multiprocessing ?
i am planning set up this powershell script on windows task scheduler.

Comment: How does the list "increase by 5 within the 1 minutes never end"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: i meant "there are other process running and transferring  files to the specific folder which number of files will be increase by 5 files in 1 minute". So my loading process should run every time. i will remove files from specific folder once it inserted to DB.

Comment: Or should i use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task ? i need to decide which way is better if someone has experience then please direct me

Comment: IMHO you can't really expect a good answer for this. You'll do much better (and can prove to you mangers why you did what you did) if you build test cases for each possibility. But seems most likely bottle neck would be inserting data into DB, do you have that well designed and monitored? OR you have your loading process run each type in a loop and then look at your timing info and see which is best for your environment. Maybe there are differences at 2am (for instance) that uncover other tuning problems you need to fix. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could use runspaces. Try this:

```
$Files = @('File1','File2','File3') #list of your files

$Throttle = 10 #number of threads
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $Throttle)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$Jobs = @()
$ScriptBlock = {
    Param($File)
    #place your executeStoredProcedure function inside the script block or make sure it will be loaded with the appropriate module via profile     
    executeStoredProcedure -value sp_load_table_crm -filename ($File.Name) -conn #heres your function and its parameters
}

$Files | % {
    $File = $_
    $Job = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($File)
    $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      Pipe = $Job
      Result = $Job.BeginInvoke()
   }
}

Write-Host "Waiting.." -NoNewline
Do {
   Write-Host "." -NoNewline
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} While ( $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)
Write-Host "All jobs completed!"

$Results = @()
ForEach ($Job in $Jobs)
{   $Results += $Job.Pipe.EndInvoke($Job.Result)
}
$Results | ft -Wrap -AutoSize
```

Comment: Glad to be proven wrong. I learned something. I hope it helps the O.P. Good luck to all.

Comment: @KirillPashkov, thank you for script, however it's working no issue but it seems not calling procedure. When i call procedure without your script the procedure was called in powershell. And i did debut on this script but process wasn't stop anywhere. Where am i making a mistake.

Comment: @user347918, make sure you put executeStoredProcedure function defenition into $ScriptBlock so it's can recognize it.